# What value for length field for Freescale PowerPC Security Engine 2.0, when using Link Tables?

Tags: security, aes, powerpc

I am working on the code to use the security engine of my MPC83XX with Openssl.
I can already encrypt/decrypt AES up to 64KByte of data.
The problem comes with data greater than 64KByte since the maximum value of the length-bits is 65535.

I can assume the data is always in one piece on the Ram.
So now I am collecting all the data in a Link Table and use the pointer to the table instead of the pointer to the data and set the J bit to 1.
Now I am not sure what a value I should use for the length-bits since 0 would mean the Dword will be ignored.
The real length of the data is too also big for 16 bit.

http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/app_note/AN2755.pdf?fpsp=1
Possible Informations can be found in Chapter 8.

Answer (score 0):

You set LENGTH to the length of the data. See Page 19:

> For any sequence of data parcels accessed by a link table or chain of link tables, the combined lengths of the parcels (the sum of their LENGTH and/or EXTENT fields) must equal the combined lengths of the link table memory segments (SEGLEN fields). Otherwise the channel sets the appropriate error bit in the Channel Pointer Status Register...

I'm not sure what mode you're using (and the documentation seems unnecessarily confusing!) but for the usual cipher modes (CBC/CTR/CFB/OFB) the the usual method is simply to chain AES invocations, reusing the same context. You might be able to do this by simply setting "Pointer Dword1" and "Pointer Dword5" to the same thing. There's very little documentation, though; I can't work out where it gets the IV from.